# Unable to clickon actionbar on robotium

Tags: android, android-layout, actionbarsherlock, robotium

Hi I am new to robotium and currently testing android "actionbaritems" in my application, i used the following code ,

```
assertTrue(solo.searchText("Log In";));

solo.clickOnButton("Log In";); 

solo.waitForActivity(LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME); 

assertTrue(solo.searchText("Forgot password?";));

solo.clearEditText(0); 

solo.enterText(0, "stest123";);

solo.enterText(1, "123456";);

solo.waitForActivity(LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME);

 final EditText editText = solo.getEditText(1); // Create a runnable which triggers the 

onEditorAction callback Runnable runnable = new Runnable()

 { 

public void run() 

{ 
editText.onEditorAction(EditorInfo.IME_ACTION_DONE); 

} 
}; // Use Solo to get the current activity, and pass our runnable to the UI // thread. 

solo.getCurrentActivity().runOnUiThread(runnable); 

solo.waitForActivity(LAUNCHER_ACTIVITY_FULL_CLASSNAME); 

System.out.println(solo.getCurrentActivity().getLocalClassName().toString()); 

getInstrumentation().invokeContextMenuAction(getActivity(),3,0); 

solo.clickOnText("Nearby";);

solo.sleep(1000); 

View actionbarItem1 = solo.getView(2);

solo.clickOnView(actionbarItem1);
```

i cant able to click on the actionbaritem can anyone advise where i went wrong at code?
Since i dont have the **apk's source** i cant pass it through regular methods, any alternative to this or any idea where i went wrong?
thanks in advance

Answer (score 2):

You're doing something quite odd here:

```
View actionbarItem1 = solo.getView(2);
```

The `solo.getView(int id)` method takes an id of a view from the R.id. (just like a path)

You have a class in a file named R.java where all the ids are referenced. When you create a view it generates an id for your View. Each id matches a view.

```
public static final class id {
    public static final int fancy_action_item_id=0x7f07016a;
}
```

The method `findViewById(int id)` will help you get the View you want by giving it the id.
Maybe you should proceed this way:

```
View actionBarItem1 = yourActivity.findViewById(R.id.fancy_action_item_id);
solo.clickOnView(actionBarItem1);
```

Comment: View actionBarItem1 = yourActivity.findViewById(R.id.fancy_action_item_id); for this we need apk source right?but in the question they have mentioned there is no apk source,other than using r.id anyother things can be done?

Comment: i dont have access to apk source,as @user2458346 mentioned the viewbyid need source of it